# Jython error in eclipse ImportError: No module named java.lang.InterruptedException :

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython, importerror

I am using Jython 2.5.3 version to integrate my python scripts with java.
But while running the script I am getting an error while importing any java class. For example:

> File "C:\Jython.2.3\Lib\threading.py", line 1, in \r\n
>   import java.lang.InterruptedException\r\n ImportError: No module named
>   java.lang.InterruptedException\r\n')

I tried looking for a solution and found a command clspack --auto, but that also didn't work for me.

The use case is simple :
I have a python file which has an import statement 
    from java.lang import InterruptedException 
I have, installed jython 2.5.3. And I have setup the interprater as 
    Pydev->Interpraters->Jython Interprater->path/to/jython.jar

PS:When I run jython from command line I can import the java modules, wihout any problem.
The problem only occurs while using eclipse.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details. How can this problem be reproduced?

Comment: The use case is simple ,I have a main file which has an import statement

from java.lang import InterruptedException

I have, installed jython 2.5.3.
And I have set p the interprater as shown in Pydev->Interpraters->Jython Interprater->path/to/jython.jar

Comment: If you want to clarify something, please edit the question. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.